# Forester repair

Tags: engine, subaru, forester, computer

If anyone can help.  I have error code P1700-TPS Circuit Malfunction-Check codes in TCM.  Error Code P0731-Gear 1 Incorrect Ratio    Error Code P0122  TPS Switch A Circuit-Low Input.  I have asked this before.  I do not have expertise to solve these.  Does anyone know a great Subaru Mechanic that can solve this car and is it worth my time and money to fix.
I don't mind driving to a place that I know it can get fixed correctly.  Live in area code 15853   Thanks

Comment: what are some of the issues you are seeing with the car? sounds like shifting/driveability issues?

Comment: Yes  I have to manually shift if I am climbing a hill. Also will not accelerate as it should when pressing gas pedal

Comment: Have you checked your transmission fluid levels?

Comment: Yes  But I will recheck this morning

Comment: Did you ever adjust the tps with a multimeter?